# Qual padrão é utilizado para tratar SQLSTATE em PDOException?

Tags: php

Não sei se sou eu que não entendi como funciona o `SQLSTATE`, porém no `MySQL` muitos erros não possuem um `SQLSTATE`, e quando pego a `Exception` do `PDO`, o código que me é retornado é o `SQLSTATE` ao invés do código de erro que é próprio do driver do banco.

A aplicação na qual estou trabalhando não irá utilizar outros bancos, portanto não vejo problema em pegar o código do driver, porém a questão que me intriga é que se por padrão o `::PDOException->getCode()` retorna um `SQLSTATE`, então deve ser muito utilizado, porém não compreendi como, já que é ambíguo.

> **Exemplo**: Vamos supor que eu possua uma classe que faça procedimentos comuns e precise apenas retornar mensagens ao usuário, se deu certo, ou se fahou e o motivo.
>
> Para evitar o mesmo código, eu teria um método que faça o tratamento dessas exceptions, recebendo a exception, onde o método irá ver qual o seu tipo e seu código de erro, e me retornar uma mensagem padrão.
>
> Caso o código do SQLSTATE retornado fosse 23000, onde ele é retornado em operações de insert, delete, update que possuem problemas de integridade, campos que não podem ser nulos, e mais uma variedade de coisas, como eu iria distinguir e entregar a mensagem correta?

Fiz uma implementação do exemplo.

```
public function remover()
{
    ids = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'checkbox', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
    try
    {
        $this->con->beginTransaction();
        $cidadeDao = new CidadeDao($this->con);
        $n = $cidadeDao->delete($ids, $this->usuario);
        $this->con->commit();
        $this->response['message'] = "$n cidades foram excluídas com sucesso";
        $this->response['rows'] = $n;
    } 
    catch (Exception $ex) 
    {
        $this->handleResponseException($ex);
    }

    $this->view->renderJSON($this->response);
}
```

E um handler para tratar essas exceptions comuns e apenas retornar uma mensagem de erro (nesse caso não preciso tratar nada, é apenas mensagem mesmo)

```
protected function handleResponseException(Exception $ex)
{
    $this->response['error'] = true;

    switch( get_class($ex) )        
    {
        case 'UnexpectedValueException':
            // ..
        break;

        case 'PDOException':

            try { $this->con->rollBack(); }
            catch (Exception $ex) { /** ... **/ }

            switch( (int) $ex->getCode() )
            {
                case 1022: 
                    $this->response['message'] = "Registro duplicado";
                break;

                case 1451:
                    $this->response['message'] = "Há registros relacionados"
                break;

                default:
                    $this->response['message'] = "Ocorreu um erro na consulta com o banco de dados";
                break;
            }    
        break;
    }    
}
```

Supondo que o `$ex->getCode()` me retornasse o código do driver, eu saberia qual mensagem entregar, mas ele retorna um `SQLSTATE`, como vou distinguir isso pela ambiguidade dos códigos?

Existe algum padrão para fazer isso, ou o que eu estou fazendo pode ser considerado uma má prática (ao meu ponto de vista resolve o problema e evita código, mas não sei se seria o correto).

Comment: Dentro do `catch` não seria melhor pegar a informação 'de quem sabe' (PDOStatement ou PDO) do que da exception? ou o resultado é o mesmo? sugiro que passe o resultado de `errorInfo()` no throw que deve ter no `delete()` para `handleResponseException`, o erro especifico está na chave `1` array.

Comment: Se eu trocar a parte do $ex->getCode() por $ex->errorInfo[1] como sugerido, eu consigo pegar o código do erro específico, acredito que vou utilizar dessa forma. Porém o que me intrigou foi a questão do SQLSTATE ser ambíguo, por isso me levou a me questionar se eu realmente estou fazendo certo, e não uma "gambiarra".

Comment: o sqlstate é como se fosse a categoria do erro ex autenticação, falhas genericas etc. Ahhh legal, não tinha certeza se a excetion tinha o método `errorInfo()`, assim(passando direto) simplifica mais. :)